# Determining the "size" of a font

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

In Plain TeX (and really as a TeX primitive), `\font\myfont=cmr8 at 10pt` and `\font\myfont\cmr10` both create fonts with "sizes" of 10pt. I want to be able to use this value to generate specific vertical spacing (e.g. always double, single, 1.1, 1.2 spaced) in a redefined macro of `\font` (it would use `\afterassignment` with `\font` to retain the normal semantics, especially the variability of putting a) nothing, b) at, or c) scaled). `\fontdimen` doesn't appear to provide this dimension. Although hacky, is there a representative character that I could create a box with and measure the height of that, or is there a more natural way to get this value?

I am able to use a macro `\def\font#1=#2@#3{...}`, but this breaks the old semantics. Note: this is a plain TeX question, so I want to avoid relying on higher level font frameworks.

Comment: I would use ``\fontcharht\font`\( + \fontchardp\font`\( ``

Comment: if pdftex is an option, you could use `\pdffontsize`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the actual size instead of an approximation like the size of the parenthesis, you can use `\fontname`: `\fontname` always includes the size, except when the font is loaded in it's designsize. But if the font is loaded in it's designsize, you can load it again at a scaled size and extract the designsize from that.

The actual code looks a bit complicated because  we have to scan for  `at`  in `cmr10 at 12pt` and the `at` has weird catcodes:

```
\begingroup
  \edef\specialAt{{ \string a\string t }}%
  \def\x#1{%
    \def\getfontsize##1=##2{% The user level macro
      \expandafter\getfontsizE\fontname##2#1\relax{##1}%
    }%
    \def\getfontsizE##1#1##2\relax##3{%
      \ifx*##2*% Loaded at designsize
        \begingroup
          \font\tmpfont"##1" scaled 2000
          \getfontsize\dimen0=\tmpfont
          \divide\dimen0 by 2
          \expandafter
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\getfontsiZe\the\dimen0\relax{##3}%
      \else% Otherwise #2 holds the size. But is is followed by " at ", so we have to strip that
        \getfontsiZE{##3}##2%
      \fi
    }%
    \def\getfontsiZE##1##2#1{##1=##2}% Strip " at "
    \def\getfontsiZe##1\relax##2{##2=##1}
  }
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\endgroup
\expandafter\x\specialAt

% Let's try using it: What is the size of \tenrm?
\getfontsize\dimen0=\tenrm
{\tt\string\tenrm} has size \the\dimen0.

\font\cmrXVII=cmr17\relax
\getfontsize\dimen0=\cmrXVII
cmr17 has size \the\dimen0.
\bye
```

Of course, you can combine this with egreg's answer to automatically assign the size of every loaded font to some macro.

[image]

Comment: I have replaced this as the accepted answer because the parenthesis method breaks on ptmr/ptmb (Times New Roman) fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `\xfont` with the same syntax as `\font`, but so that `\xfont\foo=cmr10` will also define `\foosize` with replacement text the height plus depth of a parenthesis in the font (as suggested by Ulrike Fischer).

```
\def\xfont#1{%
  % #1 = font selection control sequence
  \begingroup\escapechar=-1
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\fontnametmp{\string#1}}\x
  \afterassignment\setfontsize\font#1%
}
\def\setfontsize{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\csname\fontnametmp\endcsname(}%
  \dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 \dp0
  \expandafter\edef\csname\fontnametmp size\endcsname{\the\dimen0}%
}

\xfont\fontA=cmr8 at 10pt
\immediate\write20{\fontA = \meaning\fontA\space --- \fontAsize}

\xfont\fontB=cmr5 scaled 2000
\immediate\write20{\fontB = \meaning\fontB\space --- \fontBsize}

\xfont\fontC=cmr17
\immediate\write20{\fontC = \meaning\fontC\space --- \fontCsize}

\xfont\fontD=cmbx10
\immediate\write20{\fontD = \meaning\fontD\space --- \fontDsize}

\bye
```

This will produce, on the terminal,

```
\fontA = select font cmr8 at 10.0pt --- 10.0pt
\fontB = select font cmr5 at 10.0pt --- 10.0pt
\fontC = select font cmr17 --- 17.24997pt
\fontD = select font cmbx10 --- 10.0pt
```

Comment: Why does `cmr17` have a size of `17.24997pt`?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Because that's the height plus depth of the parenthesis. The size declared in the TFM file is actually `(DESIGNSIZE R 17.279999)`, but this information is not available to TeX.

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't the same apply to cmr8, cmr10, cmr12 (or in the above, cmbx10) — why don't they also have higher sizes than in the font name? (Sorry, I know this isn't strictly relevant to this question/answer and maybe I can look it up somewhere, just asking because it seems interesting.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I guess you have to ask Knuth for this.